# Xunit project dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, xunit

I have a strange problem. I am trying to use DI for my Xunit project so I can inject two services.

Example:

```
 public class Users_AddOrUpdateUsers_Should
    {
        public Users_AddOrUpdateUsers_Should(ICloudGraphServiceClient cloudGraphServiceClient, IHttpDevOpsServiceClient httpDevOpsServiceClient)
        {
            this._cloudGraphServiceClient = cloudGraphServiceClient;
            this._httpDevOpsServiceClient = httpDevOpsServiceClient;
        }

        [Fact]
        [Trait("Category", "WorkflowTest")]
        public async Task ReturnCorrectResult_WhenInputIsValid()
        {
            //Test Logic
        }
 
        private readonly ICloudGraphServiceClient _cloudGraphServiceClient;
        private readonly IHttpDevOpsServiceClient _httpDevOpsServiceClient;
    }
```

Currently, I have a project called `UserManagement.Tests` (where the class `Users_AddOrUpdateUsers_Should` is located), which reference `UserManagement` project. In the Startup of `UserManagement`, I added Singelton for the two services:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // Rest of the code

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpDevOpsServiceClient, HttpDevOpsServiceClient>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICloudGraphServiceClient, CloudGraphServiceClient>();
        }
    }
```

When I try to use DI this way, its throw exception:

> The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: ICloudGraphServiceClient cloudGraphServiceClient, IHttpDevOpsServiceClient httpDevOpsServiceClient

I try to use `IClassFixture<ICloudGraphServiceClient>, IClassFixture<IHttpDevOpsServiceClient>` , but its throw this exception:

> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Class fixture type 'AzureGraph.ICloudGraphServiceClient' may only define a single public constructor.) (Class fixture type 'Clients.IHttpDevOpsServiceClient' may only define a single public constructor.) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: ICloudGraphServiceClient cloudGraphServiceClient, IHttpDevOpsServiceClient httpDevOpsServiceClient)

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @Ali 
Use Moq to mock/create instance of dependencies 
You will not get DI in XUnit test project

Comment: refer this like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423714/mocking-using-moq-in-c-sharp on how to use Moq